# Replace list object dictionary values with values of another dictionary, if value/key pairs of two dictionaries match

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries like these:

```
dict1 = {'parent1': ['AAA','BBB'],'parent2': ['AAA','CCC'],'parent3': ['ZZZ', 'BBB']}
dict2 = {'AAA': 'alfa','BBB': 'beta','CCC': 'gamma', 'ZZZ':'epsilon'}
```

I would like to get the following dictionary

```
dict3 = {'parent1': ['alfa','beta'],'parent2': ['alfa','gamma'],'parent3': ['epsilon', 'beta']}
```

where the values of the dict1 stored in lists, are replaced with dict2 values if matching with the dict2 keys.

I tried

```
dict3={k: dict2.get(v, v) for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

but it returns

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're missing an iteration on the `v` values (which are lists).

```
dict1 = {'parent1': ['AAA','BBB'],'parent2': ['AAA','CCC'],'parent3': ['ZZZ', 'BBB']}
dict2 = {'AAA': 'alfa','BBB': 'beta','CCC': 'gamma', 'ZZZ':'epsilon'}

dict3={k: [dict2.get(i, i) for i in v] for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

result:

```
{'parent3': ['epsilon', 'beta'], 'parent2': ['alfa', 'gamma'], 'parent1': ['alfa', 'beta']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Less pythonic but does the job aswell. Excally the same only written out.

```
 dict3={k: [dict2[v[0]], dict2[v[1]]] for k, v in dict1.items()}
 prints {'parent3': ['epsilon', 'beta'], 'parent2': ['alfa', 'gamma'], 'parent1': ['alfa', 'beta']}
```

Edited:

```
 dict3={k: [dict2.get(v[0],v[0]), dict2.get(v[1],v[1])] for k, v in dict1.items()}
 prints {'parent3': ['epsilon', 'beta'], 'parent2': ['alfa', 'gamma'], 'parent1': ['alfa', 'beta']}
```

Comment: doesn't handle the case where values are not in `dict2`

Comment: True I read the question wrong though i said that dict2 had always the values of dict1

Comment: Now our answers are exacly the same ;) just depends if you like a extra for loop or not and if the dict1 always contains list with two values.